# Run a while loop in pyQt5 using QThread, assigning true and false on stop buttons

Tags: python, pyqt5, qthread

I got a project that listens to the microphone if I ever press start. I am so new to pyqt5 so I don't really know Qthreading that much, plus most of the examples are progress bars and for loops. I want that when it presses start it runs the while loop of recording audio for 10 seconds, identifying it, and doing again. And that it only stops when I press stop, a variable is now False. Now this is what I came up with. I am sorry if it looks dumb because I don't really know that much from Qthread. I just want to be able to run this one in particular.

```
class AvisoWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Aviso_Main.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(AvisoWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.is_Played = True
        self.start_btn.clicked.connect(self.startClicked)
        self.stop_btn.clicked.connect(self.stopClicked)

    def startClicked(self):
        while self.is_Played == True:
            listen()
            time.sleep(0.01)

    def stopClicked(self):
        self.is_Played = False
        self.finished.emit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = AvisoWindow()
    threading.Thread(target=form.__init__(), daemon=True).start()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, nothing related to the UI shall *ever* be run or accessed in an external thread. Blocking functions and while loops (unless it's guaranteed that they exit almost instantly) should also be avoided, as they block the event loop preventing proper redrawing of the UI and user interaction.

Even assuming that directly using threads with UI was possible, your attempt has two important problems:

1. `__init__()` should never be called externally (and, even in that case, it expects *at least* the instance as argument);
2. the `target` argument of Thread expects a *callable* (a reference to a function), but you're already *calling* the method (using the parentheses), so it would use the returned value of that called function (which is usually `None` for an init);

In order to use threads that have to react to an UI environment, in Qt you should create a subclass of QThread that acts as your "worker".

```
class Worker(QThread):
    result = pyqtSignal(str)
    def run(self):
        self.keepRunning = True
        while self.keepRunning:
            res = someFunctionThatReturnsAString()
            self.result.emit(res)
            time.sleep(0.01)

    def stop(self):
        self.keepRunning = False


class AvisoWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Aviso_Main.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(AvisoWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.result.connect(self.resultReceived)
        self.start_btn.clicked.connect(self.startClicked)
        self.stop_btn.clicked.connect(self.stopClicked)

    def startClicked(self):
        if not self.worker.isRunning():
            self.worker.start()

    def stopClicked(self):
        self.worker.stop()

    def resultReceived(self, result):
        print(result)
```

Comment: When I did this solution but instead of stop the thread with a button I stopped with close event of the window and "QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running" is prompt

Comment: @StraightCoding add `self.worker.wait()` in the `closeEvent()` or `self.wait()` in `stop()` if you are completely sure that you will *always* stop it when quitting.

Comment: Oh thank you, it works. Can you explain why this happened?

Comment: @StraightCoding `stop()` just sets the flag, but the `time.sleep()` is probably still waiting, so the `while` loop isn't exited yet and the thread is still running when it's being destroyed by the application quit. [`wait()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#wait) blocks until the thread has finished (`run()` has returned) so that it can be properly destroyed upon completion. (please use "@username")